# Account sharing rules based on province/state code

Tags: platform-bug, sharing-rule

I have a criteria based sharing rule that is supposed to provide access to a group of users based on the shipping province/state code of the accounts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SharingRules xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <sharingCriteriaRules>
        <fullName>SharingRuleName</fullName>
        <accessLevel>Read</accessLevel>
        <accountSettings>
            <caseAccessLevel>Read</caseAccessLevel>
            <contactAccessLevel>Read</contactAccessLevel>
            <opportunityAccessLevel>Read</opportunityAccessLevel>
        </accountSettings>
        <label>SharingRuleName</label>
        <sharedTo>
            <group>RegionName</group>
        </sharedTo>
        <criteriaItems>
            <field>ShippingStateCode</field>
            <operation>equals</operation>
            <value>11,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,34,37,41,61,65</value>
        </criteriaItems>
    </sharingCriteriaRules>
</SharingRules>
```

The province codes in Salesforce for China are numeric values that seem to be based on the old [ISO 3166-2:CN codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:CN):

[image]

What actually gets created is completely different from the metadata that gets deployed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SharingRules xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <sharingCriteriaRules>
        <fullName>SharingRuleName</fullName>
        <accessLevel>Read</accessLevel>
        <accountSettings>
            <caseAccessLevel>Read</caseAccessLevel>
            <contactAccessLevel>Read</contactAccessLevel>
            <opportunityAccessLevel>Read</opportunityAccessLevel>
        </accountSettings>
        <label>SharingRuleName</label>
        <sharedTo>
            <group>RegionName</group>
        </sharedTo>
        <criteriaItems>
            <field>ShippingStateCode</field>
            <operation>equals</operation>
            <value>浙江,重庆市,安徽,四川,澳门,福建省,江西,山东,澳大利亚首都特区,下加利福尼亚州,亚历山德里亚,海南,贝卢诺省</value> 
        </criteriaItems>
    </sharingCriteriaRules>
</SharingRules>
```

Not only have my province codes changed to a textual description, they are for **completely different regions**, some of which are in different countries and don't even use numeric identifiers:

[image]

What I'm seeing here happens just the same when the rule is created through the ui.

Has anyone else seen this issue before, and are there any suggestions on how to work around this issue?